# DNS Server and Amazon dynamic IPs

Tags: linux, email, amazon-ec2, domain-name-system

I'm about to configure a dns server in order to get rid of amazon mail sending limits. As private ip's are dynamic, how can i associate host+FQDN with a private ip and make sure the association is always valid although ip's get changed in a lapsus of time. Should the dns server get notificated every time the ip gets changed? And how?
Thanks in advanced!

PD: I think using elastic IPs is not a valid solution as AMIs comunicate each other through dynamic private IPs.

Answer (score 1):

On the AWS network, the public DNS for an amazon elastic IP resolves internally, so you won't be charged for bandwidth since your request won't leave the network.  You will be able to assign the same elastic IP to a new server if you need to, and you won't have to change the software that points to the public DNS for the elastic IP since it will resolve appropriately.  Knowing this is way it works is this still not a valid solution?

Either way, sending email from an AWS instance is not a good idea.  Since many spammers use AWS for spam, most of the AWS public IPs are blacklisted and your emails will never get through.  We use [DynDNS's Dyn Standard SMTP](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/outbound.html) and haven't had any issues with emails not going through.